# change webpack configuration in angular 9

Tags: angular, webpack

I am using angular 9, and CesiumJS.

I recently updated my Cesium so that it will include build in typescript definitions.

For that, I need to import my definitions like this :

`import { Cartesian3 } from "cesium";`

The problem is, at build time, I get the following error.

> WARNING in ./node_modules/cesium/Source/Core/buildModuleUrl.js 114:14-21
> Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

> ERROR in ./node_modules/cesium/Source/Core/Resource.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Users**\Documents\Repository***\node_modules\cesium\Source\Core'

no, on github I found this issue https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium/issues/8673

and apparently, we just need to specify webpack to not use the dependency

```
    node: {
        // Resolve node module use of fs
        fs: "empty",
        Buffer: false,
        http: "empty",
        https: "empty",
        zlib: "empty"
    },
```

but this is very tricky part, and I am afraid to break something. Do I need to eject the web pack configuration ( like in react ?) and then modify and maintain it manually just for this ?

Is there a simple way to avoid this build error ?

EDIT : I used this => https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack

and change my config with

extra-webpack.config.ts

```
import * as webpack from "webpack";

export default {
  node: {
    fs: "empty",
    Buffer: false,
    http: "empty",
    https: "empty",
    zlib: "empty",
  },
} as webpack.Configuration;
```

and

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./extra-webpack.config.ts",
              "mergeStrategies": {
                "node": "replace"
              }
            },
...
```

but now I have

> Schema validation failed with the following errors:
> Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(browserTarget).

Answer (score 1):

I think this bug occur by Ivy.
In Angular version 9, Ivy is the default. For compatibility with current workflows during the update process, you can choose to opt out of Ivy and continue using the previous compiler, View Engine. Before disabling Ivy, check out the debugging recommendations in the Ivy Compatibility Guide.

Another solution is to change angular.json:

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
                    ...
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/../...scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/cesium/Source/Core/Resource.js",
            ]
          },
```